# Video thumbnail that links to other page for playing

Tags: html, css, video

I have a small thumbnail for a video file.
The user can hover over the thumbnail and then it lights up.
When the user clicks the thumbnail video, it should lead him to a category page where the video can be played may the user choose to do so.

Now my code lets the video be played directly in the thumbnail upon clicking, thats not what I want.

Is it possible to have the user click my video thumbnail with the "video player look" and that the video does not play, but instead the user is directed to another page where he can play the video in full screen?? I got the link working, the only problem I have is that the video should not play in thumbnail but that the user can see the "video player look with all the controls" so he knows it is a video that he can view in the category page.

HTML:

```
<div class="videofile">
                        <video controls="">
                        <source src="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AAnimaci%C3%B3n_de_escanciar.ogv" type="video/ogv"</video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.videofile:hover {
    opacity:.3
}
```

FIDDLE:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/p5bLravp/)

Answer (score 0):

A video control that is never used would for sure be overkill for this - just add a play button as watermark above an image and then link that?